# Create factor based on multiple column values

Tags: r, r-factor

I am trying to create a new column (factor) that holds the col name of the largest value in a dataframe.  Think of this as the proportion of soil type for each polygon (rows) in a dataset. I want to create a new column that holds only the highest proportion soil name. Example:

```
soil <- data.frame(soil1=c(0.75,0.25,0.25),soil2=c(0.25,0.75,0.75))
```

Now I want output that looks like this:

```
soil$out <- c('soil1','soil2', 'soil2')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` for that matter:

```
soil$out <- names(soil)[apply(soil, 1, which.max)]
```

The `apply(soil, 1, which.max)` determines which columns holds the (first) maximum value and that is then passed to `names(soil)` to determine the corresponding column name.

Comment: Similar idea: `names(soil)[max.col(soil)]`

Answer (score 2):

use `ifelse` as it is vectorized

```
soil$out <- ifelse(soil$soil1 > soil$soil2, "soil1", "soil2")
```

Note: if you'd need the maximum values themselves (rather than the col names) use `pmax` (which is also vectorized)

```
soil$out2 <-pmax(soil$soil1, soil$soil2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient way,

```
soil = data.frame(soil1=c(0.75,0.25,0.25),soil2=c(0.25,0.75,0.75))

#> soil
#  soil1 soil2
#1  0.75  0.25
#2  0.25  0.75
#3  0.25  0.75

#Calculate max proportion for each row
soil.max<-apply(soil,1,max)
#soil.max
#[1] 0.75 0.75 0.75


#For each row, find the column index while matching with max proportion value calculated in previous step
soil$max.col<-sapply(1:nrow(soil),function(x) colnames(soil)[grep(soil.max[x],soil[x,])] )
soil
#  soil1 soil2 max.col
#1  0.75  0.25   soil1
#2  0.25  0.75   soil2
#3  0.25  0.75   soil2
```